# How enable text selection in green div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

See problem at http://jsfiddle.net/jLatbqj0/81/

After click "Add Div" button new div inserted.
But i can't select text in it.
I add "user-select:text" in css, but its not helped.
My CSS:

```
.child {
  user-select: text; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
}
```

How enable text selection?

Comment: You should display the code here as well

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @Evgeny Shiryaev isnt my solution fixed your problem?

Comment: @Rahul, no, i must use appendChild

Answer (score -1):

I've been able to select it when changing the `z-index` (display div above canvas) and the `user-select` to `all`:

```
.child {
  user-select: all !important;  
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome 58

Answer (score -1):

My solution would be little different here

instead messing with `user-select` I suggest to insert your `.child` div before `.vis-network` and make `.child` divs `z-index: 2`

this way you dont need to mess with css `user-select`

see http://jsfiddle.net/jLatbqj0/95/